# How to convert a wav file to a JSON file

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, wav

I have a WAV file called student, now I want to convert this to a text and download this text as a JSON file.

The WAV file (audio) has the following content "Hello, I'm Michel. I am a student of Georgian college"

The JSON file needs to have the above content as a string.

Basically, convert speech to text.

Comment: If you want raw bytes, `file_obj.read()` would do after opening the file in byte mode.

Comment: @heemayl - The following thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529520/how-to-convert-a-wav-file-bytes-like-object does that . But, I am don't know how to convert that back to a json file

Comment: This question sounds like *"I have a cat named Oscar, now I want to convert this to a dog and raise this dog as a poodle"* to me. How do you intend to convert a WAV file to JSON? Also, *why*?

Comment: What do you want the JSON file to contain? Just an array of numbers from 0 to 255 for the raw bytes of the file? A dict representing the WAV header and an array of frames each of which is an array of numbers in the appropriate range representing the samples in the file? Something else?

Comment: Are you asking how to do Speech to Text?

Comment: @Aran-Fey  I have edited the question. Yes, I want to convert speech to text.

Comment: @abarnert I have edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite a lot of speech recognition softwares depend on [HMM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_Markov_model) or Hidden Markov Model. This approach works on the assumption that a speech signal, when viewed on a short enough timescale (say, ten milliseconds), can be reasonably approximated as a stationary process - meaning, a process in which statistical properties do not change over time. The speech is divided into 10 mm fragments and is mapped to a vector of real numbers known as [cepstral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum) coefficients and then these vectors are matched to Phonemes. This is a very high overview of a typical speech recognition system.

Now, coming back to the requirement that you have, a little research would have brought you to libraries like -

- [apipi](https://pypi.org/project/apiai/)
- [Google cloud speech](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-speech/)
- [Pocketsphinx](https://pypi.org/project/pocketsphinx/)
- [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) and there are more..

Now using [SpeechRecognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) is as simple as (taken from [source code](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/examples/audio_transcribe.py) and tried on my computer) -

```
import speech_recognition as sr
from os import path
AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath(__file__)), "english.wav")
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.AudioFile(AUDIO_FILE) as source:
    audio = r.record(source)  # read the entire audio file
try:
    print("Sphinx thinks you said " + r.recognize_sphinx(audio))
except sr.UnknownValueError:
    print("Sphinx could not understand audio")
except sr.RequestError as e:
    print("Sphinx error; {0}".format(e))
```

And voila, it works, in *ten* lines of code, thanks to amazing people developing these :)

**Edit** - You need to have [PocketSphinx](https://pypi.org/project/pocketsphinx/) set up for this code to work.

Comment: For me, AUDIO_FILE = path.join(path.dirname(path.realpath('__file__')), "english.wav") worked.