# How to change a wave.open file to a normal file object without saving the file

Tags: python, wave

I am trying to use the python `speech_recognition` to get text from a set of frames in a `wave` file got from a client.

I have tried to use `speech_recognition` on a `wave` object but this doesn't work and it only works on files (or the path to a file)

I tried:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import wave

r = sr.Recognizer()

# code to get frames

waveFile = wave.open(file, 'wb')
waveFile.setnchannels(1)
waveFile.setsampwidth(2)
waveFile.setframerate(44100)
waveFile.writeframes(frames) # from client

f = sr.AudioFile(waveFile)
with f as source:
    audio_file = r.record(source)
text = r.recognize_google(audio_data=audio_file, language="en")
print(text)
```

Then I get the error:

> AssertionError: Given audio file must be a filename string or a file-like object

So I am wondering if there is a way to convert a wave object to a normal file-like object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert a wav file -> bytes-like object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35529520/how-to-convert-a-wav-file-bytes-like-object)

Comment: On what line do you get this error?

Comment: The `f = sr.AudioFile(waveFile)` line is the error